# 8 gauge stranded copper wire?

Tags: wire

Where in the UK can I buy 8 gauge stranded copper wire for high current applications (so not rly thin wire) relatively cheaply.

I've had a look around and couldn't find anywhere -

HELP!!

Comment: this is not the shopping forum

Comment: Shopping questions are off topic here, rephrase your qeustion.

Comment: Convert (from whichever of SWG or AWG you're using - they are different!) to mm^2, round up to next standard size, and buy that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume "8 guage" is AWG (North American size).  That is 0.1285 inch or 3.2639
mm diameter, so you might look for 3.25 or 3.5 mm wire in the UK.  I don't know what the standard metric wire sizes are...

Comment: Since he's in the UK he might want SWG rather than AWG.

Comment: Metric wire sizes are given in sqaure millimeters, not millimeters diameter. Confusingly people often don't bother to write the superscript 2.

Answer (score 1):

4mm D is 16sqmm is approximately  AWG 8 
£2.39/m

http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Copper-Welding-Cable-16mm-25mm-35mm-50mm-70mm-Battery-Cable-Earth-Cable-PVC-/232046811588?var=&hash=item36071159c4%3Am%3Amwwmvm_rjXE3Uj6QEs7EAWQ